Failing to create a documantion of my AnyLogic model by clicking on tools then create documentation
I have created a model in Anylogic 8.8 ple using the fluid library. When I try to create the model documentation by clicking on "tools" then selecting "create document" I am encountering an error that says "The file is blocked by another process. Choose another file name or close the blocking process and try again"
I have closed all programs on my pc
I have closed all models on my AnyLogic
I have changed the name of the model
But i am still getting the error

tried it with a simple example model?
